# Codeigniter routing where there is no route

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Currently I have a bunch of routes set up, and what I want to do is in the event of someone landing on my domain if its not a valid route I want them to go through a specific contoller. All the while retaining the welcome controller. for the domain itself. is this at all possible?

Comment: Just set the 404 route page to loads your wanted controller/method

Comment: hmm that could work? maybe.. ill try it in the 404, was hoping to keep the 404 as well though, which i guess wouldn't apply since anything thats not a controller I'd want to essentially in concept 404 or default to this.. so 4040 would inadvertantly fail..

Comment: not valid route equals to not existing page which is 404..
I don't see how you can have 2 rules for both things at the same time..

Comment: Yea.. thats what I was kinda saying.. thinking out loud in a matter of speaking

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$route['404_override']` in your `application/config/routes.php` ([bottom of the docs page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)). It works just like any other rule (assing a `controller/method` to it. Inside that controller you can use the `$this->uri->segment()` or `uri_string()` or other input sources to decide what to do.

Just remember to send out 404 response headers with `show_404()` or otherwise if the request does in fact is looking for something non-existent.

#### Update

As it turns out, current (2.1 stable) branch doesn't seem to handle sub-directories for 404_override, in the Router class [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Router.php#L293), and [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Router.php#L338) should try to check if there's a third segment with the subdir or not. Also, there's a [pull request](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/939) intended to fix this, not yet merged.

Comment: Currently it is serving me with a 500 error. The controller path I am using is a valid path and works through other means of routing

Comment: ahh.. apparently you can't have a controller in a sub folder when using the 404 method?

Comment: I'm affraid no, looking into the router source, [it seems kinda unhandled](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Router.php#L338). Here should be some logic to see if there's more than two segments...

Comment: yea currently attempting to work that up, and then redirect accordingly however I a running into an issue with the redirect. It should be redirecting to `/profile/url_segment` (using `$this->uri->segment(1)`) as I only care about the first segment in this case. however doing `redirect('/profile/'$this->uri->segment(1))` its redirecting to `/profile/profile` even though when I echo the combination out its `/profile/whatever.the.segment`

Comment: The `$this->uri->segment()` method indexes segments form **1**, so your uri is `/profile/some.segment` then `segment(1) == 'profile'` and `segment(2) == 'some.segment'`.

Comment: ahh figured out my problem, had to readjust my profile route to match thought I had done that